# How do I hide other submenu except current submenu in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, web, submenu

I want to hiding other submenu, when using current submenu.

ex)

```
A
  a
  a
B
// using a

A
B
 b
 b
// using b
```

I worked below by mouseleave.

```
<li id="admin" class="sidebar-list" ng-mouseenter="option=true" ng-mouseleave="option=false">
    <a href="#/admin/security">Admin <span class="menu-icon fa fa-cog"></span></a>
    <ul class="admin-sub" ng-if="option==true">
      <li>
        <a href="#/admin/security"> - Admin Management</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

but I want to modify this, In current submenu page open the current submenu. but It is not working. help me please.

```
  <li id="report" class="sidebar-list" ng-mouseenter="option1=true;option2=false;">
    <a href="#/reports/resource">Reports <span class="menu-icon fa fa-file-text-o"></span></a>
    <ul class="report-sub" ng-if="option2==true && toggle==true">
      <li>
        <a href="#/reports/resource"> - Resource</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="admin" class="sidebar-list" ng-mouseenter="option1=false;option2=true">
    <a href="#/admin/security">Admin <span class="menu-icon fa fa-cog"></span></a>
    <ul class="admin-sub" ng-if="option2==true">
      <li>
        <a href="#/admin/security"> - Admin Management</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

Comment: Post a fiddle for this issue, it would be easier to understand your issue

Comment: are you expecting like this? https://jsfiddle.net/ctx0vex2/1/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#cssmenu').prepend('<div id="menu-button">Menu</div>');
  $('#cssmenu #menu-button').on('click', function(){
    var menu = $(this).next('ul');
    if (menu.hasClass('open')) {
      menu.removeClass('open');
    } else {
      menu.addClass('open');
    }
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  z-index: 100;
  width: auto;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #39B1CC;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #51bbd2 0%, #2d97af 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #51bbd2), color-stop(100%, #2d97af));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #51bbd2 0%, #2d97af 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #51bbd2 0%, #2d97af 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #51bbd2 0%, #2d97af 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #51bbd2 0%, #2d97af 100%);
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  background: url('bg.png');
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 18px 25px 21px 25px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.12);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #D3ECED;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #32a9c3;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 45px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #D3ECED;
  right: 17px;
  top: 22px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub.active > a::after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a {
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  top: 60px;
  z-index: 9999;
  padding-top: 6px;
  font-size: 13px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: top 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: top 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: top 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: top 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease-in;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
  top: -4px;
  left: 20px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li > ul::after {
  left: auto;
  right: 20px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right-color: #ffffff;
  top: 11px;
  left: -4px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul::after {
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: #ffffff;
  left: auto;
  right: -4px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
  top: 120px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
  top: 52px;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-left: 6px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  padding-right: 6px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: 180px;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 11px 25px;
  width: 180px;
  color: #777777;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.active > a {
  color: #333333;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a {
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #777777;
  right: 17px;
  top: 14px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: #777777;
  right: auto;
  left: 17px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub.active > a::after,
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub:hover > a::after {
  border-left-color: #333333;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub.active > a::after,
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub:hover > a::after {
  border-right-color: #333333;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}
@media all and (max-width: 800px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #cssmenu {
    background: #39B1CC;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul.open {
    display: block;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  #cssmenu.align-right > ul {
    float: none;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-center > ul {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li,
  #cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li > a {
    padding: 18px 25px 18px 25px;
    border-right: 0;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
  #cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #D3ECED;
    padding: 18px 25px 18px 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background: url('bg.png');
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul,
  #cssmenu ul li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu > ul > li > ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right > ul > li > ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul li:hover > ul {
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
    top: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding-left: 35px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 45px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button::after {
    display: block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    border-top: 2px solid #D3ECED;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #D3ECED;
    right: 25px;
    top: 18px;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button::before {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    border-top: 2px solid #D3ECED;
    right: 25px;
    top: 28px;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a::after,
  #cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- Icon Library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="cssmenu">
  <ul>
     <li class="active has-sub"><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i> Reports</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Reports 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Reports 2</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Admin</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Admin 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Admin 2</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-cog"></i> Test</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Test 2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Test 3</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-ellipsis-v"></i> More</a>
        <ul>
           <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">More 1</a>
              <ul>
                 <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">More 1.1</a>
                    <ul>
                       <li><a href="#">More 1.1.1</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">More 1.1.2</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">More 1.1.3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
                 <li><a href="#">More 1.2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">More 1.3</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">More 2</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">More 2.1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">More 2.2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">More 2.3</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">More 2.4</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">More 3</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">More 3.1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">More 3.2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">More 3.3</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">More 3.4</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">More 3.5</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">More 3.6</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">More 4</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">More 4.1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">More 4.2</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```